# Explain streaming k-means

Tags: k-means, online-algorithms

I need to cluster 22 million vectors, each of which has a dimension of 1024. Can anyone explain streaming k-means to me?

Comment: By ["streaming kmeans"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=streaming+kmeans), I assume you refer to an [tag:online] algorithm for k-means, meaning that we don't have all the data available when we cluster, but start with some initial data and cluster that - then more data arrives (one observation at a time, or in batches), and we *update* our clustering each time, instead of clustering wholly anew. If so, please be a little more specific as to what you do not understand, because otherwise your question will likely be closed as "too broad". Thank you!

Comment: @StephanKolassa, why not develop that into an answer? It would be brief, but would be appropriate for the question, as far as I can see.

Comment: By streaming, i mean using a streaming algorithm, an algorithm that prcesses streams.  (data can't fit in memory)

Answer (score 7):

["Streaming kmeans"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=streaming+kmeans) typically refers to what is also known as "[online](/questions/tagged/online) kmeans". [Online algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) refer to computations that are performed iteratively, with data arriving *during* the computation in single observations or in batches, in contrast to "offline" algorithms, where all the data are available when the computation starts. Typically, some intermediate result is calculated based on initial data and then modified as new data arrive. For instance, [exponential smoothing](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7) is a forecasting algorithm that is very naturally performed online.

In the specific case of [k-means](/questions/tagged/k-means), we would first apply a standard [k-means](/questions/tagged/k-means) algorithm to cluster an initial dataset. Then, the cluster centers would be updated as new data arrive. Such algorithms often keep and update clusterings with different numbers of clusters, because the optimal number of clusters may change over time as data arrives.

Alternative names for [online](/questions/tagged/online) algorithms include "sequential algorithms", and a number of other synonyms as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm). For the specific case of online k-means, this SO question looks like a good place to start: [Online k-means clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3698532/452096)